# How can I call parameterized constructor of default type from a parameterized constructor of type public which is in another class?

Tags: java, inheritance, default-constructor

Class B is inherited from Class A.

Class A have parameterized constructor of access type default which is not accessible (default:it can be accessible from different class but from same package.)

How can i access my constructor of default visibility from another class?

Here I want to access `A(int id1,String s)` from `public B(int id1,int h1)` ,by calling `super(999,"super");` it bombards error that create a new constructor

Edit:Class A and B are in same project

```
 public class A {

          A(int id1,String s)
        {
            System.out.println("in parameterized constructor of class A");

        }

    public class B  extends A{

        public B(int id1,int h1)
        {
            super(999,"super");//The constructor A(int, String) is undefined

            System.out.println("in parameterized constructor of class B");

        }
```

Comment: Are your classes in different packages?
If yes, use `protected` modifier for A constructor: `protected A(int id1,String s) ...`

Comment: Edit:Class A and B are in same project

Comment: Project doesn't matter as far as the JVM is concerned. All that matters is, are they in the same package? Btw if class A doesn't have a default constructor (constructor with no args) and they aren't in same package, your code won't compile even without a call to super().

Comment: And FYI you're using terms in the wrong context. "Parameterized" is about generics, "default constructor" is a constructor with on arguments, use "default access" instead.

Comment: I think if we write paremeterized constructor and ignore default constructor and write :  A a2=new A(3700,"A"); it dont give error

Comment: After 5 mins so I can't edit previous comment, here you go: Btw if class A has a default constructor (constructor with no args) with default access, and they aren't in same package, your code won't compile even without a call to super().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `B extends A`, `A` only has a default visibility constructor, and `B` is not in the same package as `A`, then there is absolutely 100% no way to make `B` compile at all.  None of `A`'s constructors will be visible to `B` and that is absolutely necessary.

(You can use this deliberately when you need to have a class that needs subclasses but you don't want it to be subclassable outside the package.)

Comment: so according to you package is of more importance?if two classes are in same package then and only then constructor of default access can be accessed and even if there are in (same programme but sub-classes )it wont matter?

Comment: Yes.  As far as Java is concerned there is no such thing as a project.